# Remove non-existent devices from "Calls on Other Devices" on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id

On my iPhone 8 running iOS 12.1, under:

- "Settings / Cellular / Calls on Other Devices",
- "Settings / Phone / Calls on Other Devices",
- "Settings / Messages / Text Message Forwarding"…

…I see two list items for test macOS user accounts I created and deleted in troubleshooting another issue.

These two non-existent devices don't appear in the list of devices:

- at the bottom of "Settings / Apple ID",
- on https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage,
- on my Mac under "System Preferences / iCloud / Account Details / Devices".

I've tried toggling the faux devices, toggling "Calls on Other Devices", and rebooting the phone and the notebook.

I assume now, in retrospect, that I should've logged out of iCloud on the test macOS user accounts before deleting them (including their home folders), but I'm pretty sure now that's no longer an option.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I had an iMac showing twice within "Calls on other Devices" on an iPhone

The following got it fixed for me.

1. Removed my iMac from the iCloud account
2. Logged into iCloud again on the iMac
3. Logged in FaceTime on the iMac
4. Switched off/on "Calls on other Devices" on the iPhone

Hope this helps